# When adding an IP address drop rule to IPtables it converts it to a domainname/url. Why?

Tags: linux, iptables

So I have been playing around with IPTables and bash scripts to auto detect bruteforce attacks on my server (averaging about 50 per day minimum - is this normal?). My server logs these attacks for me and then every morning dumps the new attack IP addresses to IPtables permanently blocking them.

I don't think I have a problem, but I'm just curious to know what's happening. Basically my script is adding the IP addresses, but when I display the current rules with a iptables -L command, the IPs appear to get converted. Why is this?

For example, I run this command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 95.9.203.101 -j DROP
```

and when I do a `iptables -L`, it shows up as this:

```
DROP       all  --  95.9.203.101.static.ttnet.com.tr  anywhere
```

Why does it not just leave it as the IP address?

It's random as well. Some stay as IP addresses, others convert. For example all of these were added as IP addresses. I have no idea why they come up like this when displaying all rules:

```
DROP       all  --  95.9.203.101.static.ttnet.com.tr  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  11.189.188.61.broad.nc.sc.dynamic.163data.com.cn  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  58.218.211.166       anywhere            
DROP       all  --  denaos.datemas.de    anywhere            
DROP       all  --  117.6.130.80         anywhere            
DROP       all  --  223.203.217.202      anywhere            
DROP       all  --  182.100.67.114       anywhere            
DROP       all  --  222.187.198.50       anywhere            
DROP       all  --  182.100.67.112       anywhere            
DROP       all  --  s15283632.onlinehome-server.info  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  202.109.143.18       anywhere            
DROP       all  --  95.9.203.101.static.ttnet.com.tr  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  11.189.188.61.broad.nc.sc.dynamic.163data.com.cn  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  58.218.211.166       anywhere
```

Any idea?

Also, when I run `iptables -L`, it pauses on some of the rules before continue to output to the screen. I assume this is because it's looking up the IP address? I have tried to find an explanation around this, but can't seem to find one. Is this just how it works. Are the IPs actually stored in the config, but when I run `iptables -L` it tries to reverse?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the IP addresses and port numbers without showing their names, you can use the option `-n`. So, your command will be

```
iptables -L -n
```

If you look at the manual `man iptables`, you can read:

> -n, --numeric
>       Numeric output.  IP addresses and port numbers will be printed in numeric format.  By default, the program will try to display  them
>   as host names, network names, or services (whenever applicable).

When not using `-n` option, it pauses because it is trying to resolve IPs to names.